# Compose function with two arguments

Tags: function, haskell, function-composition, pointfree

I ran into something that threw me off today. I was trying to define a function equivalent to [`Data.Text.commonPrefixes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text.html#v:commonPrefixes) that throws away everything but the prefix.

The following works:

```
commonPrefix :: Text -> Text -> Maybe Text
commonPrefix a b = fmap firstTriple $ Text.commonPrefixes a b

firstTriple :: (a, b, c) -> a
firstTriple (a, _, _) = a
```

I originally tried doing it like this, which doesn't work:

```
commonPrefix :: Text -> Text -> Maybe Text
commonPrefix = fmap firstTriple . Text.commonPrefixes
```

Is there a way to define this function as a composition?

Comment: `(fmap firstTriple .) . Text.commonPrefixes` ?

Comment: It looks like `fmap (fmap firstTriple) . Text.commonPrefixes` works too. Thanks everyone!